# Mapped Network Drive Dropping

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-7

We have a Head Office with a file server containing shared folders. Group Policy is used to map all of the network drives on every domain joined PC. One of our remote sites, connects back to Head Office via a VPN. Everyone on this site seems to be able to use the mapped network drives without issue however, one user seems to have a problem where after a while, some of the files inside her drive will disappear (everything else is fine and her connection seems normal). I am able to fix the problem by manually remapping the drive however, this is happening several times a day. Has anyone else come across this before? What can I do to fix it?

I believe that there could be a dropout briefly, and only the cached folders appear (causing the rest to disappear) however, I don't understand why the drive wouldn't automatically reconnect when she reopens it, considering the connection seems fine, and other employees don't get the same issue.

The users are running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the "Offline" files feature is enabled in windows.

[This URL explains how to turn this off.](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/07/turn-on-off-offline-files-in-windows-7/)